# Ncurses output of 'sl' changes if running on a terminal verses from a log?

Tags: terminal, escaping, ncurses, ioctl

I'm writing a terminal, and was trying to use steam locomotive as a test bed, and ran into an unusual problem.  Even in a regular terminal like xterm or mate-terminal, the output is different if you run the application, i.e. `sl` verses if you log it to a file i.e. `sl > sl.txt` then cat it `cat sl.txt`

This is particularly pronounced on `sl-h` where in the first few seconds, codes are output which would make the X/O for the railroad crossing which if catted show incorrectly putting the X/O at the beginning of the line.

[image: bad truncated output from SL]

It seems that there is an `ioctl` that's happening that somehow changes newline behavior to advance to the next line, but not return back to the beginning.   I.e. `strace sl-h 2> sllog.txt` shows: `ioctl(1, SNDCTL_TMR_STOP or TCSETSW, {B38400 opost isig -icanon echo ...}) = 0`

How would you be able to detect this as a terminal?  What systems are in place?  Why wouldn't ncurses just use escape sequences to convey this information?  There's a lot of questions that I'm not sure how to handle in my terminal.

Answer (score 1):

ncurses (like Unix curses) puts the terminal into *raw mode* for two reasons:

- ability to read single characters (and ignore signals such as *quit* that might be bound to them), and
- ability to manage the *output*, including movement around the screen with fewer characters than a simple `printf`.

In raw mode, the Unix-style conversion of *line-feed* to *carriage-return* and *line-feed* is disabled.  That lets ncurses move directly down by one row (in the same column) with a single characters.  Cursor addressing would typically use 6 or more characters.  Even a cursor-down would use 3 characters.

Incidentally, that treatment of *line-feed* is the reason why the terminal descriptions often have the cursor-down capability assigned to a *line-feed*.

Comment: Then a better question is how can a terminal detect that the slave on the other end of the PTS is requesting raw mode?

Comment: The terminal mode can be checked using [**`tcgetattr`**](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904875/functions/tcgetattr.html)

Comment: You can't practically poll that every time you want to draw a character to the screen.  It also seems that terminals like sl and xterm don't do this... I can't seem to find the mechanism within them to detect the change.

Comment: The terminal ***driver*** does the transformation of line-feed, etc., so the terminal sees only the raw stream of data.

Comment: Hmm... me, being the terminal, I have to at some point decide to move the cursor down a line when I see a character 10... And I have to decide whether or not I want to move the cursor to the beginning of the line.